# Is there any serializers field type to implement tag field

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Is there any serializer field type to implement Tag field
to create a form to get some information from the client I'm using the below class

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ClientInfoForm(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    fname = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    #Tag = something can implement Tag type field
```

and to show this I use the below function

```
class UserAPI(APIView):
    serializer_class = ClientInfoForm
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):        
        data = request.data
        User.save(data)
```

Comment: You should make a Form and a Serializer as two separate things.

Comment: OK. I want a webpage that has that field.APIView makes a webpage for me and I don't have enough knowledge about UI and HTML.  Can you show me how to implement this?